# DBML - Stored Procedure Modelling Failure

Tags: linq-to-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which models fine when I comment out a single simple `IF` statement:

```
IF LEN(@myVariable) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @myVariable = SUBSTRING(@myVariable, 1, LEN(@myVariable)-1)
    END
```

If I do not comment out this line, I get the error:

> The return types for the following stored procedures could not be detected.  Set the return type for each stored procedure in the Properties window. dbo.my_stored_procedure

Why would this statement cause the auto-generation of the returned type to fail?

When I comment out this line of code, I get the return type I am expecting, along with all of its properties (modelled automatically in the DBML)

Is there a setting I am missing?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What do you return? The return type may be undetectable when it's not specified what happens when the `IF` condition is not hit.

Comment: Hi Gert, when I comment out the `IF` condition you see above, I get the correct type.  The stored procedure returns a list of columns and it correctly gets modeled into a class with properties representing each of the columns (as it should.) I only experience an undetectable return type with the `IF` condition is not commented out.  I'm not sure why the `IF` statement above would make the return type undetectable...?

Comment: Yes, maybe, because it is undefined if `LEN(@myVariable) <= 0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Gert for sending me in the right direction.  The stored procedure modelled correctly without any issues after changing the statement:

```
IF LEN(@myVariable) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @myVariable = SUBSTRING(@myVariable, 1, LEN(@myVariable)-1)
    END
```

to:

```
IF LEN(@myVariable) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @myVariable = LEFT(@myVariable, NULLIF(LEN(@myVariable)-1, -1))
    END
```